# Como criar entidades com chave composta no doctrine?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, doctrine, orm

Tenho um banco de dados que trabalha com chaves compostas, e estou implementando a utilização do *framework Laravel*.

Essa é estrutura do meu banco:
[image: Relacionamento do banco]
Estou utilizando o ***doctrine*** como ORM e descobri que eu não consigo gerar automaticamente as entidades do banco, já que as tabelas possuem chaves compostas. Estou utilizando o comando `php artisan doctrine:convert:mapping annotation ./entidades --from-database --force`. O retorno a este comando é :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
It is not possible to map entity 'FinContaspagar' with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity 'FinContaspagarDetalhe#grupo'.
```

Deste modo, estou criando as entidades manualmente, porém eu segui o tutorial do ***doctrine*** em relação a criação das entidades *`@ManyToOne @OneToMany`* mas ainda não consegui criar a relação da maneira correta. Alguém sabe uma maneira ou ferramenta para gerar essas entidades ou tem algum exemplo como este de varias chaves compostas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando a versão 2+ do doctrine uma maneira de mapear suas entidades manualmente é colocando @Id nos seus atributos que fazem parte da sua chave primária, neste caso existe uma restrição quanto ao uso do @GeneratedValue, você não pode usa-lo. 
Aqui o exemplo da própria doc do framework:
[Chave primária composta](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)